# How do I scrape a website and output data to xml file with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape data using Nokogiri and HTTParty and can scrape data off a website successfully and print it to the console but I can't work out how to output the data to an xml file in the repo.

Right now the code looks like this:

```
class Scraper

  attr_accessor :parse_page

  def initialize
    doc = HTTParty.get("https://store.nike.com/gb/en_gb/pw/mens-nikeid-lifestyle-shoes/1k9Z7puZoneZoi3?ref=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F")
    @parse_page ||= Nokogiri::HTML(doc)
  end

  def get_names
    item_container.css(".product-display-name").css("p").children.map { |name| name.text }.compact
  end

  def get_prices
    item_container.css(".product-price").css("span.local").children.map { |price| price.text }.compact
  end

  private

  def item_container
    parse_page.css(".grid-item-info")
  end

  scraper = Scraper.new
  names = scraper.get_names
  prices = scraper.get_prices

  (0...prices.size).each do |index|
    puts " - - - Index #{index + 1} - - -"
    puts "Name: #{names[index]} | Price: #{prices[index]}"
  end

end
```

I've tried changing the .each method to include a File.write() but all it ever does is write the last line of the output into the xml file. I would appreciate any insight as to how to parse the data correctly, I am new to scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried changing the .each method to include a File.write() but all it ever does is write the last line of the output into the xml file.

Is the `File.write` method inside the `each` loop? I guess what's happening here is You are overwriting the file on every iteration and that's why you are seeing only the last line.

Try putting the `each` loop inside the block of the `File.open` method like:

```
File.open(yourfile, 'w') do |file|
  (0...prices.size).each do |index|
    file.write("your text")
  end
end
```

I also recommend reading about the [Nokogiri::XML::Builder](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder) and then saving it's output to the file.

Comment: I think thats done it. I got confused on the scoping. Thank you for this!